# PyArray_BOOL declaration & working with Numpy array of bools in C extension

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I have a NumPy array of bools in my code that I wish to write a C extension to.
When I try to get a contiguous array in order to use in my C routine, I use:

```
arr_mask = (PyArrayObject *)
    PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(mask, PyArray_BOOL, 2, 2);
```

But I get the compiler error that PyArray_BOOL is not declared.

```
xor_masking.c:44:40: error: ‘PyArray_BOOL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Why it is so? Is this type undeclared? If it is so, how can I introduce my array of bools to C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NPY_BOOL rather than PyArray_BOOL. Also, you will need to be using the numpy header rather than the numeric header if you are still using the numeric header like in one of your other questions.